# Append function at certain Interval

Tags: jquery, html, delay, setinterval

I am having 3 div which have a simple animation to slide from right to left. How to set intervals by applying functions to them.

For example 2nd div should slide at 1st delay and should animate after 3rd like that.

## Html

```
<div class="Objects"></div>
<div class="Objects"></div>
<div class="Objects"></div>
<button class="trigger">Click Me</button>
```

## Css

```
.Objects{ width:200px; height:100px; background:#ccc; margin:10px; position:relative; left:500px;}
```

## Script

```
$(".trigger").click(function () {
  $(".Objects").animate({left:'0px'});
});
```

Working Link

http://jsfiddle.net/vivekdx/xZn3u/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using the [setTimeout command](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout).
It executes a function after a specified delay.

While iterating over the jQuery Array containing the selected divs, I multiply the base delay with the current index. So every call to the `slideLeft` function is delayed more with each iteration.

I changed your script to the following:

```
var slideLeft = function($item) {
    $item.animate({left:'0px'});
}

$(".trigger").click(function () {
//      $(".Objects").animate({left:'0px'});

    $(".Objects").each(function(index, item) {
        setTimeout(slideLeft, 200 * (index + 1), $(item));
    });

});
```

Working demo based on your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xZn3u/1/

Comment: Thanks Jo. Is there a way to do the same to a addClassfunction at certain time interval

Comment: If I understand you correctly you could add something like `$item.addClass("slided");` to the `slideLeft` function. Or if you want the class to be added after the animation has finished, you could add a callback to the animate function and adding the class there.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following code and it will work for you..

```
$(".trigger").click(function (){
   var el = $(".Objects");
   $.each( el, function( key, value ) {
     var tm = 1000*key;
     $(value).delay(tm).animate({left:'0px'});
   });
});
```

Please take a look at following link to see the output

http://jsfiddle.net/xZn3u/4/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's animate has a 'complete' property which is called when the animation is completed.
Example:

```
$item.animate({left:'0px'}, function() {
    // next call
});
```

see [api](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)